# In PHP's Laravel, how do I clear laravel.log?

Tags: php, laravel-4

I'm new to Laravel and PHP in general, and I'm trying to clear my errorLog. The current errorlog that I'm using is Laravel's laravel.log file that is in /app/storage/logs.

Is there an easy way to clear the laravel.log file? Is it safe to delete it and it'll rebuild when needed?

I'm using the latest version of Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: `cat /dev/null > /app/storage/logs/laravel.log` - http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/92384/how-to-empty-a-log-file

Comment: `echo "" > /app/storage/logs/laravel.log` also works, and the most efficient is `truncate -s 0 /app/storage/logs/laravel.log`. More info : http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88808/empty-the-contents-of-a-file

Comment: If you delete it, the laravel.log file will automatically regenerate once an entry tries to write to it. So yes you can `rm storage\logs\laravel.log` if you know nothing else needs it, and it will reappear clean and new.

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Echoing an empty string to it would work, like this :

```
echo "" > storage/logs/laravel.log
```

The [most efficient](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88808/empty-the-contents-of-a-file) would be to `truncate` it to a size of zero :

```
truncate -s 0 /app/storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: Depending on your OS you might have to use `./` and not just a `/` for the current directory `truncate -s 0 ./storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: use @Adnan Rasheed 's answer to clear logs from your controller , meaning from browser address string.

Comment: [Remove First n Lines of a Large Text File on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/410206/783280)

Answer (score 60):

Here's a reusable `artisan` command that will save you time and effort :)

```php
Artisan::command('logs:clear', function() {
    
    exec('rm -f ' . storage_path('logs/*.log'));

    exec('rm -f ' . base_path('*.log'));
    
    $this->comment('Logs have been cleared!');
    
})->describe('Clear log files');
```

Drop this in `routes/console.php` then just run `php artisan logs:clear`

---

**Updates:**

- Added `base_path('*.log')` for `npm`, `composer` etc logs in root directory.
- Added `-f` to `rm` function to suppress the `No such file or directory` message.

Comment: getting the error:"'rm' is not recognized as an internal or external command"

Comment: @NaimR. I'm assuming you are using Windows? This is for Linux/macOS sorry, don't know anything about Windows.

Comment: I will add this line at the end so the log file is created again
`exec('touch ' . storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));`

Comment: @Fakher why create it again if Laravel creates it for you? If you want to empty it out just do this: `echo > laravel.log`

Answer (score 20):

Simply just add this line where you want to clear the log.
`file_put_contents(storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),'');`

Comment: This worked perfect in my helpers.php file along side other custom logging functions.

Answer (score 17):

You can also create custom artisan command.

First, run command `php artisan make:command Log/ClearLogFile` to create custom command file.

Then, open file on `Console/Commands/Log/ClearLogFile.php` (depends on you Laravel version, currently I'm using 5.5 version)

After that, you need to define the custom command code, take a look

```
// Define command name
protected $signature = 'log:clear';

// Add description to your command
protected $description = 'Clear Laravel log';

// Create your own custom command
public function handle(){
    exec('echo "" > ' . storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));
    $this->info('Logs have been cleared');
}
```

Then, you only need to run just like other php artisan command,

```
php artisan log:clear
```

Thanks, for @emotality [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52469765/4494207)

Comment: I got error when I run php artisan log:clear "There are no commands defined in the "log" namespace".

Comment: @Nurul  Looks like you defined the wrong namespace. First, make sure your file `ClearLogFile.php ` are in the path `app/Console/Commands/Log/ClearLogFile.php`. Second, please check the namespace (at the top of code), make sure it looks like this `namespace App\Console\Commands\Log;`. Then try run `php artisan list` to check is the command available. If error still occured, please check this one, https://stackoverflow.com/q/32396158/4494207

Answer (score 16):

Easiest way for me is using vim.

```
$ vim laravel.log

Then type ggdG

Then :wq save and quit.
```

Notes:
gg - moves cursor to first line

d - delete

G - to the end of the file

Comment: Thanks for not just giving the solution, but explaining the arguments.  You may have a bright future on StackOverflow!  :)

Answer (score 10):

This worked for me :

```
echo "" > storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Comment: This is simplest solution! Nice!

Answer (score 5):

From your Laravel directory:

```
rm storage/logs/laravel-*.log
```

Comment: we can't simply delete the file, other services might be using those logs and deleting the file might cause issues

Answer (score 5):

I found this solution works well for windows

```
Artisan::command('logs:clear', function() {
   array_map('unlink', array_filter((array) glob(storage_path('logs/*.log'))));
   $this->comment('Logs have been cleared!');
})->describe('Clear log files');
```

Run `php artisan logs:clear`

Answer (score 4):

For Laravel 5, it would be

```
truncate -s 0 storage/logs/laravel.log
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do: `: > storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/19232130)

Comment: How does this not provide answer to the question?

Comment: The question is already answered long ago and it is accepted, what is the intention of adding a new answer to this question without any explanation?

Comment: I'm simply offering an alternative shorter syntax. If that's a bad thing according to you then I'm starting to really doubt the purpose of this site.

Comment: your solution is always welcome but how this differs from the accepted answer and you are not given any explanation to your answer.

Comment: 1. Sree what a jacka$$ 
2. This is the best solution to the problem

Answer (score 2):

There is very easy way to clear log with `php artisan log:clear` command using **Laravel More Command** Package.

First Install Laravel More Command

> `composer require theanik/laravel-more-command --dev`

Then Run

> `php artisan log:clear`

The above will deleted all old log data from ***/storage/logs/*** directory.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick the following line in my controller method when I am running the SQL query listener:

`exec("truncate -s 0 " . storage_path('/logs/laravel.log'));`

If you use a different `monolog` channel setup you might want to tweak the name of your log file.

Answer (score 1):

To complete @emotality response. Here is the code for **Windows**.

```
Artisan::command('logs:clear', function() {
    exec('echo "" > ' . storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));
    $this->info('Logs have been cleared');
})->describe('Clear log files');
```

Drop it in `routes/console.php`
And use it like this:

```
php artisan logs:clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to tinker `php artisan tinker`

Then run

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redis;
Redis::resolve('horizon')->flushall();
```

Expected response:

```
> Redis::resolve('horizon')->flushall();
= true
>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just add a bit to be sure before clearing.

```
Artisan::command('log:clear', function() {
    if ($this->confirm('Do you wish to continue?')) {
        exec('echo "" > ' . storage_path('logs/laravel.log'));
        $this->info('Logs have been cleared');        
    }
})->describe('Clear Laravel log');
```