# "There are no commands defined in the 'command' namespace." after running command:make in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

Just like in title. I'm trying to run from artisan

```
php artisan command:make NameOfCommand
```

but all I see is

```
There are no commands defined in the "command" namespace.
```

Any idea what is this?

Comment: After you create your command using `php artisan make:command NameOfCommand` as @Narendrasingh answer suggests, then you must register your command in the app/console/kernel as @Alejandro answer suggest in order for the command to work.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have misplaced the command it is

```
php artisan make:command NameOfCommand
```

and not

```
php artisan command:make NameOfCommand
```

If you have simply write `php artisan` within your command prompt it'll show you the list of commands over there have a look

[image]

Comment: thank you, I shouldn't believe in all that I see in tutorials

Answer (score 59):

As the documentation says (Current version is 5.2 at this moment):

> Once your command is finished, you need to register it with Artisan so
>   it will be available for use. This is done within the
>   app/Console/Kernel.php file.

in the Kernel.php file you must add:

    `protected $commands = [
      Commands\NameOfCommand::class
    ];`

(ref: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/artisan#registering-commands)

Comment: This is it. (Laravel 8 user here)

Comment: Yes @AkshayKNair , we have to register our command in kernel also.

Answer (score 5):

In laravel 5.2 use php artisan make:console NameOfCommand